# Update() not being called for dynamically created instance of class

Tags: c#, dynamic, unity-game-engine

In Unity 3d I have created an instance of a class I wrote called Timer.

```
Timer readyTimer = new Timer("Ready Timer");
```

I just create the new instance and pass the type of timer I would like this instance to be. My issue is that since I am creating this dynamically, the Update() function is never called.

Is there a way to dynamically create an instance of a class such as this and still allow the MonoBehavior functions to work as they are intended?

Comment: The class ***must be a MonoBehavior*** ... it's that simple.

Comment: It's possible your fundamental issue is this: confusingly, in Unity, they forgot to add the concept of a **preload scene**.  In 100% of Unity projects, the first thing you do is add a "Scene Zero" which loads first. It contains things like AI, sound effects, scoring, play management -- all the "singleton-like things" you always have in a game. (Obviously you can't actually use singletons in a game engine.) Of course they are all marked `DontDestroyOnLoad`.  Bizarrely unity forgot to include this concept (that's Unity all over) which is the single most basic thing when you're making games.

Comment: What you then probably do is just add a trivial piece of syntactic sugar to make it very easy to access those components "from anywhere".  http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1124859/view.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update is invoked on game objects. Have a prefab with your designed Timer component then instanciate that prefab into your scene : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Comment: I didn't think of that. In my case instantiating a gameobject and adding the script as a component all dynamically would probably be the best way to handle this then. Thank you.

Comment: Update is called on MonoBehaviour components that implement the Update. GameObject is just a container for the components. Just wrong wording but the idea is right.

Comment: And components are added with AddComponent to a game object.